# how can I update the Line chart values from API Response in react native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

My API respond seven days moisture record, now i want to extract the seven days name and moisture values. my Api response is in JSON so I use for loop to extract the days and moisture values, now problem is that when by using useState I set the moisture and days values ,and write days and moisture in line chart data it show NAN in place of days and moisturereading. please help to solve this problem. this is my first work in React Native so please correct me if i am wrong at any line of code.
this is My Code

`

```
const [days, setdays] = useState([])
const [moisturereading, setMoistureReading] = useState([])
useEffect(()=>{
      //deviceinfo()
     callapi()
    })
    function callapi() {
    fetch('http://192.168.8.1/mobile/DeviceDataStats?deviceid=1' )
  .then(data=>data.json())
  .then(data2=>{
    console.log(data2)
    //listday[]
    //listmoisture[]
     for(var i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
      setdays([...days,(data2.Table[i].DayName).slice(0, 3)])
      setMoistureReading([...level,(data2.Table[i].Moisturevalue)])
     //level.push(data2.Table[i].Moisturevalue)
    //days.push((data2.Table[i].DayName).slice(0, 3))
      //console.log(data2.Table[i].DayName)
      }
  })
  .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
  
  }  


**This is the Line Chart data** 

const data = {
  labels: ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"], //{days} i want to update labels with days            
  datasets: [
    {
   data:[29, 45, 28, 80, 91, 43,55],//{moisturereading} want to update data with moisturereading
    
      color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(134, 65, 244, ${opacity})`, // optional
      strokeWidth: 2 // optional
    }
  ],
  legend: ["Moisture Values"] // optional
}`
```

[image: linechart with hardcoded values]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First init first data

```
const [chartData,setChartData] = React.useState({
   labels: [],
   datasets: [
    {
      data:[],
      color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(134, 65, 244, ${opacity})`,
      strokeWidth: 2
    }
   ],
   legend: ["Moisture Values"]
  })
```

then call data function

```
function callapi() {
    fetch('http://192.168.8.1/mobile/DeviceDataStats?deviceid=1' )
    .then(r=>r.json())
    .then(r=>{
        //get 7 elements from array response,
        const sevens = r.Table.slice(0,7);
        // and return new array contain days
        const days = sevens.map(c=>c.DayName.slice(0, 3))
        //and return new array contain values
        const values = sevens.map(c=>c.Moisturevalue)
        //set data to state by extract old object
        setChartData({
            ...chartData,
            labels: days,
            datasets:[
                {
                    ...chartData.datasets[0],
                    data: values
                }
            ]
        })
    })
  .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
  
  }
```

final set data to chart

```
<LineChart
 data={chartData}
/>
```

call callapi() each time you want to refresh data

Comment: when i call callapi function it goes into infinite loop and system stuck here ,

Comment: @ArslanHanif  it not infinite loop, it just call callapi function each time component update, because this line of code: useEffect(()=>{
      //deviceinfo()
     callapi()
    })

Comment: you should pass param to useEffect to it execute when you want . example pass [] when you want to call when componentDidMount : useEffect(()=>{
      //deviceinfo()
     callapi()
    },[])

Comment: as i tell you about, call your function just one time, when your screen loaded. so,  useEffect(()=>{ callapi() },[]) resolved your problem

Comment: sir now it gives days and moisture value ones but on mobile it shows "error while updating property 'd' of a view managed by rnsvgpath null" any idea about that?. I much thankful for your help and guide .

Comment: @ArslanHanif maybe because there is no data in initial data, so try to set at least one data when init. const [chartData,setChartData] = React.useState({
   labels: ["label"],
   datasets: [
    {
      data:[1],
      color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(134, 65, 244, ${opacity})`,
      strokeWidth: 2
    }
   ],
   legend: ["Moisture Values"]
  })

Comment: try to console log data when you receive from api, to check data is valid

Comment: Issue is resolved by your guide , when I set initial data , the error gone, again thanks for you Guide.